# Traefik 2 with Prometheus and Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, traefik

I'm currently using Traefik 2.2 with Prometheus and Grafana.
Traefik dashboard, metrics are working, and Prometheus endpoint is enabled.
However, there are too few metrics sending to the Grafana dashboard.
Hope somebody can give some suggestions.
I tried with  prometheus:
        manualRouting: true
and entryPoint: metrics, but same result.

Thanks in advance.

Traefik labels:

```
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints.rule=hostregexp('{host:.+}')"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.abcdxyz.com`) && PathPrefix(`/api`, `/dashboard`)"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=tx7:$redacted$$"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=https-redirect@file"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik.abcdxyz.com`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=le"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"
  - "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
  - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.options=myTLS@file"
```

Traefik.yml

```
log:
  level: INFO

entryPoints:
  dashboard:
    address: :8080
  http:
    address: :80
  https:
    address: :443
  metrics:
    address: :8082

api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: false
  debug: true

serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true

certificatesResolvers:
  le:
    acme:
      httpChallenge:
        # used during the challenge
        entryPoint: http
      email: abcd@outlook.com
      storage: acme.json
      # Use Let's Encrypt Staging CA when testing!
      #caServer: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    filename: config.yml
    watch: true

accessLog: {}

# metrics

metrics:
  prometheus:
   manualRouting: true
    buckets:
      - 0.1
      - 0.3
      - 1.2
      - 5.0
    addEntryPointsLabels: true
    addServicesLabels: true

  influxdb:
    pushInterval:
     - "10s"
    addEntryPointsLabels: true
    addServicesLabels: true
    protocol: http
    database: server
    username: admin
    password: "passwd."
```

config.yml

```
http:
  routers:
    api:
      entryPoints:
        - metrics
      rule: PathPrefix(`/metrics`)
      service: prometheus@internal
```

Prometheus.yml

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 5s
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'server'
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['192.168.1.97:9090']
  - job_name: 'node_exporter'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['192.168.1.97:9100']

  - job_name: 'traefik'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['192.168.1.97:8082']

  - job_name: 'grafana'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['192.168.1.97:3000']
```